# Windows sockets accept() returning wrong value

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking

On the server side of my program, when the program hits the accept function it waits for a connection. After a connection incoming is found ( After I connect to it with my client) , the accept() method returns 1. Based on that return it tries to receive and send to socket 1 which is a wrong socket.

Here is some code from my server:

```
for(;;)
{
   if( sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)  != SOCKET_ERROR)
```

After a connection is found sConnect has the value of 1.

Why does this happen? And How do I fix it?

Comment: Add some parenthesis around `sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)`

Comment: I would make that 2 lines to make the code more readable and avoid this bug and warning that the compiler should issue for that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you compare returned by `accept` value with `SOCKET_ERROR` and assign this boolean to `sConnect`:

```
if( sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)  != SOCKET_ERROR)
```

Personally I don't like such long lines. Separate the assignment and comparison:

```
sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
if( sConnect != SOCKET_ERROR )
...
```

or add parentheses at least.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, if `accept()` fails, it returns `INVALID_SOCKET`, not `SOCKET_ERROR`.

The real problem is your `if()` statement is performing both assignment and comparison at the same time, but it is missing a required set of parenthesis for the assignment, so it is actually comparing a different value than you are expecting.  Do this instead:

```
if( (sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen)) != INVALID_SOCKET )
```

A better option is to separate the assignment and the comparison:

```
sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
if( sConnect != INVALID_SOCKET )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen);
if( sConnect  != INVALID_SOCKET)
```